# Whats wrong here?

Tags: javascript

```
function tabsOpen(x) {
 var tab = x;
return tab;
} 

function printTab(x) {
 var tabOpen = tabsOpen(tab);
 alert(tabOpen);
}
```

Why does the second function doesnt show the returned value "tab" from the first one? Thanks!

Comment: I've edited your post to format the code so it's more readable. When you post code here, please indent it by 4 characters so that the site auto-formats it for you, otherwise it's hard to read. See the instructions on the Post Question page for more details.

Comment: And not to forget 13 questions - 0 answers - member for 20 days. Seems somebody doesn't fully understand the Stack Overflow system.

Comment: as Tony rightly pointed out, you need to start accepting some answers to your questions. Otherwise people are just going to begin ignoring your questions.

Answer (score 3):

```
function printTab(x) {
 var tabOpen = tabsOpen(x);
 alert(tabOpen);
}
```

Second function has x passed into it, but then tries to pass a different variable to tabsOpen, you need to pass x into that function as '`tab`' doesn't exist in it's scope.

**Edit - Working code**

Your javascript:

```
function tabsOpen(x) {
 var tab = x;
return tab;
} 

function printTab(x) {
 var tabOpen = tabsOpen(x);
 alert(tabOpen);
}
```

And your html:

```
<button onclick="printTab(5)">lol</button>
```

Comment: Hi, that last example doesnt seem to be working either. I did exactly as you told me. Any other tips?

Comment: I've added in tested and working code.  If it's not working, paste us your entire page.